# Cutting with Boolean Modifiers

Tags: animation, modifiers

I have a scene where I need to be able to "interactively" cut a mesh.  I have set up a bounding box, and the object I need to cut is set inside.  When I move the vertices of the bounding box, the object is cut because of my implementation of a boolean modifier with the "union" property.  Here is an example:

[image]

However, the sphere is just being flattened in this image.  What I need is to be able to literally "cut" the sphere, so that it is hollow on the inside.  Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Here is how I want it to look, but with the ability to be animated.

[image]

Any help/suggestion is welcomed!

Edit:  I added a photo of how I want the image to look.

Comment: See this discussion: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?313938-Bisect-as-modifier (Bisect as modifier?)

Comment: Could you add an image of how you want to look? I'm not sure what you mean by "hollow".

Answer (score 9):

You could add a [*solidify modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Solidify) to the sphere before the boolean modifier:

[image]

Also note that you can set the boolean modifier to *Difference* and use a plane as the *Object*, it may be easier to animate than a cube.

For this to work, the normal of the plane must be facing the sphere:

[image]

You can flip the direction of the normals by

- Pressing *Flip Direction* in *3D view > Tool Shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Basic > Normals*
- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and enabling *Inside* in the *Redo menu* (either at the bottom of the *Tool Shelf*, or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>).

## Result:

[image]

Comment: If the plane is "cutting" through the Sphere, shouldn't the plane have the Boolean modifier set to Intersect? When I try your solution nothing happens, the plane and sphere are both visible and no clipping of the sphere happen (checked normals, applied scale etc)

Comment: @MicroMachine With the new bmesh solver it seems using an open plane doesn't work consistently (I've reported a bug about it [here](https://developer.blender.org/T59357)). In the meantime you can use carve on 2.7x or a closed mesh (such as a cube) in 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

If not animated:

*Edit mode*

Menu: *Mesh > Bisect*

Click and select options at left (<kbd>T</kbd> tools panel in *3D View*), like fill or quit parts.
Get it from:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Bisect

The boolean operations always try to conserve the mesh.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I need it to be animated.  If you have any more ideas, please let me know!

Comment: @Lamikins You can animate the _Plane Point_ values after using the Bisect tool.

Comment: No you can't animate operator settings.

Comment: @Lamikins You could get the parts generated with Bisect and make them separate or hide on the correct time during animation. Perhaps if you explain more about your animation could be more easy help you.

Comment: See my comment to the question, there has been talk about bisect and if it's possible to make it a modifier. But so far, you could only bisect for every frame like suggested by gabrign, which means there will be one mesh datablock for each frame of the animation with no transition in subframes.

Comment: @Rhys Ah, true. I forgot that those were operator settings, should probably do a quick test next time before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a second smaller sphere within the first one with boolean difference.

[image: modifiers]