# Object inner is black with clipping camera for cutaway view - add inner lighting?

Tags: materials, node-editor, light

I am using cutaway view with [camera clipping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects), and managed to show the cut area by geometry node, looks soo good, but see the image there is a cube with room inside,
it is black because no light can pass through...

you agree - it looks awful ;)

If I uncheck "Ray Visibility" of the object with Shadow or Diffuse it also doesn't look so good because shadows of the objects are missing in general.

Is there a node trick to bring light into the darkness...?

As a solution I also could add a pointlight into the geometry...
but is there anyting better ?

[image]

Comment: That node setup should work. Is it added to the end of the node network?

Comment: yes, this is plugged into the material output... It works in term of the organe shading but light can't pass into the inside...

Comment: It works in term of the organe shading but light can't pass into the inside... the ones in the bottom are just cubes = work. the one on the top is a representation for meshes where there is room inside = no light in the inside = black. This is the normal behavior of camera clipping - I think - because it's no a real cut in the geometry - but is there a hidden function or a kind of trick

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood. You want the exterior lighting to pass into the cube. Correct?

Comment: yes correct, It's kind of maybe not possible, because light should pass into but not through the material. Shadows which are caused by the object should be there, to ;)

Comment: The only way I can think of it being possible is to render two images. One with the side of the cube and another without, then combine them in a photo editor. But there is no way I know of to do it within the node editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the geometry is still there, even though it's not visible to the camera. Rays bouncing through the scene will still interact with such geometry.

Instead try something like in [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8602/599).

Answer (score 1):

you can do the clipping in the material nodes and make the clipped points transparent :

[image]

if you set the value of the math node to the clipping_start  of the camera then what is clipped by the camera will also be transparent ( the diffuse material is a place holder replace it with your material )

if you use the clipping in the materials only, you can clip only the desired object that has this material :

[image]