# How to fill a mesh / make solid

Tags: color

I'm a student looking at microstructures. To render proper images I need to have solid objects (e.g. emulsion droplets).

Does anyone know how to create an object/mesh that is solid in the inside, instead of hollow?

In addition: how can I add color to the outside and another color to the volume of a solid mesh? 
For example: a sphere that has a yellow outside and filled with a green material.

Thanks in advance!
Jantine.

Comment: Please specify what render engine you are using. If the outer faces of an  Object have no thickness, then to the renderer they behave like a solid object. For example a sphere with no inner walls that uses a glass shader will render like a solid marble and not like a hollow glass sphere.

Comment: I'm using cycles. For the material I'm using diffuse BSDF. I'm trying to make cross-sections of emulsion droplets, and the inside of the droplets should show up 'solid green' , with a yellow shell, to visualize what part of the droplet is used to make a cross-section.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add that information as part of the question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cross+section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I "fill" an empty object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/can-i-fill-an-empty-object)

Comment: You want something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8600/2217)?

Comment: Thanks! I'm still struggling with this, but it helps me to come closer to the answer ;)