# Interactive clipping plane

Tags: 3d-view, camera, edit-mode

In this question, [How can I easily animate cutaway views on multiple objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects) it was suggested to use the camera clipping distance as a cutting plane.

[image]

Is there a way to have an interactive cutting plane that is not parallel to the camera?

What is needed is a way to review complex geometry in real time by moving a cutting plate through the geometry in a way that does not necessarily line up with the camera view clipping planes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily animate cutaway views on multiple objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects)

Comment: LuxCoreRender has such a feature: https://wiki.luxcorerender.org/BlendLuxCore_CameraPanel#Clipping_Plane

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I think this question is asking for an interactive/viewport solution. That question seems to be about doing this in a render.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For use in the viewport, try the [clipping border](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html#view-clipping-border) <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: This only works in wireframe or solid mode unfortunately