# Rotating Camera Clipping Plane

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, eevee-render-engine, clipping

I'm trying to create a Portal Effect using Blender and I am trying to find a way to cut objects in front of the Portal cameras like in [this](https://youtu.be/cWpFZbjtSQg?t=781) video.
[image]

Unfortunately a limitation of Blender is that I cannot rotate the camera clipping plane, and just changing the clip start can only work in some situations. I found some other similar posts like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118773/interactive-clipping-plane) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects) one, but using Boolean modifiers wouldn't be preferrable since I would need to apply it to every single object in my scene. There seems to be a feature like this in [Luxcore](https://wiki.luxcorerender.org/BlendLuxCore_CameraPanel#Clipping_Plane), but essentially what I'm asking is is there a way to somehow rotate the clipping plane this in Blender? If not, is there a way to code it in? Thanks

Comment: You could do this at shader level, but it might take some work if you have lots of different materials in your scene, though a node group may alleviate somewhat