# Eevee shader to cut a section through a model

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

It is possible to achieve a "section cut" "clipping plane" shader as shown below - solved on [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/section-plane/565080/14) on the bA forums.

However, it doesn't quite solve the ability to create a cap. When two section planes are applied, it is quite obvious that it is just showing the backface and not a true cut.

I am looking for two potential ways to mitigate this issue:

1. Try to improve this shader such that a cap is shown in the simplest way possible for Eevee.
2. Modify the shader such that a thick line can be shown where the cut is made, to help visualise the cut position, similar to how SketchUp does it:

[image]

Really really appreciate if somebody can crack this - I've tried without success!

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164425/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8600/

Comment: Thanks @JachymMichal - but I have seen both of those and they do not answer my question. Both links propose shader solutions that have the same backface issue with no cap, and neither address a thicker line. A boolean does create a cap, but I am not looking for a boolean based solution (booleans are too slow in my scenario, and only affect meshes).