# How can I view a cross section of 3D objects?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

I'm looking to view 3D objects by using / adjusting cross sections is there an option to do this in Blender 2.83?

Something like this:

[image: cross section]

Most information I've seen seems overly complex https://youtu.be/JAzlC3VZDfw

Comment: Related: [How to render a floor plan while maintaining proper lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164388/78972)

Answer (score 4):

Use booleans. Create the object that you want to cut. (Make sure it is one mesh), and add a Boolean modifier. Then create another object. This will cut out of the original one as the Boolean will calculate the intersection between those two and remove it. Now all that's left to do is move the cutter to where you want it to be, and then hide it from visibility.