# How to animate cross section cutaway revealing the inside of an object?

Tags: animation, rigging, objects

I'm unsure about the exact term for this process, but it is commonly used in various animations

[image: Insider Blender Object]

I have an object and I want to animate its internal components, similar to the example shown above. I attempted to split the object and rotate one part by 180 degrees, but it didn't achieve the desired result as seen in this animation. I believe there must be a standard method for accomplishing this. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions for tutorials on this topic.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects

Comment: How does your object look like? Is it a bullet as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this effect pretty easy with geometry nodes:

using this node tree:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

Explanation:

Arc animation:

[image]

[image]

arc animation filled + extruded:

[image]

[image]

and then just boolean mesh that with your object.

Of course you have to take care that this animated cylinder is bigger than your object and "hides" your object.

https://youtu.be/d0sobB75hjg

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: glad i could help