# Is there anything like Arnold's Clip Geo in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I saw this from Lee Griggs and I wonder if there's anything similar in Cycles:
https://docs.arnoldrenderer.com/display/A5NodeRef/clip_geo

I know something similar is possible with the shader nodes:
[Cycles. Masking objects with shaders (no compositor)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173039/cycles-masking-objects-with-shaders-no-compositor)

But as you can see, the inside part in the Cycles version looks empty, the geometry is just missing. Whereas in the Arnold version, the geometry is still solid.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but, looks like boolean modifier

Comment: Might be useful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109614/fake-bool-operation-with-osl-shader and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39962/boolean-on-cycles-rays-not-on-mesh

Comment: It is not a boolean, it is a shader. Though you can somewhat obtain similar results with modifiers, it's quite different in terms of impact on performances and you can do different things with a shader (like driving it from a texture) that is way harder to do by boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's doable only with a boolean? I think I saw a node setup once which was quite close but I can't find it anymore.
There's also Blender BIM which now I'm going to test.
But if anyone has a better idea, please, let me know.