# Create heart hollow part

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves

I want to show heart's interior i.e., I wanna show the heart's inside portion by cutting heart in two parts, but I am not sure how to start? Anybody guess how to start it or is there any tutorial?

For example see the below image I want 3D model of this.
[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/how-to-animate-slices-through-geometry-with-a-different-interior-and-skin-e-g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily animate cutaway views on multiple objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects)

Comment: I don't want to show animation for the cross - section. Instead I want to create the cross section from scratch but I am not sure how to do it? I mean what should I do which practices should I follow to create 3D model. I did not create any complex structure yet.

Comment: So, this is mainly a "plumbing" modeling problem?

Comment: I'd suggest doing a search of Youtube; although a bit old (dating to 2009), there is a 12 part series on modeling the human heart in Blender by Michael Lively (cf. <https://youtu.be/ygUCu89sQpw>), although I've not watched it, and can't verify that it uses cycles. I know there are others, too.

Comment: @Prashant Tomar it seems you already found that part 11 and 12 of that series are missing... but I also think that was only about modeling the outside. Modeling the inside can be very difficult, imho, and you'll need lots of references.. if you wish to learn manual modeling. It seems that it can also obtained from CT scans, like this one https://www.embodi3d.com/files/file/64-3d-printable-human-heart-model-with-stackable-slices/

Comment: Yes @m.ardito before posting question here I already noticed that series misses 11 and 12 part. I tried so many links but no I idea how to create it. I think it will take time now, as I am a beginner with blender.

Comment: Also does anyone know that my question is not duplicate of any question still some person marked it as duplicate. Is there any way to tell them hey this is not duplicate and don't do the down vote for it :(

Comment: @PrashantTomar, I believe your question is not a duplicated (or at least not a duplicate of what is indicated as a duplicate question). You should update the question to indicate clearly what is your need to avoid it to be closed. Also, please tell if you just want some clues about how to begin with or more than that.

Comment: Thanks @lemon, I edited the question hope it will not be considered as closed.  :-|

Comment: The question was marked as duplicate because the linked one explains how to show cutaway of the object *already modeled* (and it doesn't matter with or without animation - the method is the same regardless). If your question is about modeling as well it's not a duplicate (probably), but then it's more like tutorial request (which can be closed as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked "how to start", here is a way to begin the modeling:

**Keep it simple**

A tube is a subdivided open cube:

[image]

You can extrude it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>:

[image]

You can also extrude or inset in order to have some branching out and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> allows to round (go to sphere) rapidly:

[image]

From a surface, you can also extrude to create vessels in/out puts:

[image]

Once the exterior part modeled (be sure to be happy with it). You can create the inner part using a solidify modifier, with no rim:

[image]

Then apply the modifier (only the solidify, not the subdivision) and separate the two parts using <kbd>P</kbd> then 'by loose parts'. So you can work on the inner model keeping the exterior as it is:

[image]

After that you can 'draw' the inner parts, for instance for a valve, using a bevel <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Or the knife tool:

[image]

Hope these few simple technics can help.