# Materializing a Boolean modifier in an animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials, modifiers

I'm trying to reproduce **David**'s answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/how-to-animate-slices-through-geometry-with-a-different-interior-and-skin-e-g), and make variations.

When I assign a material other than transparent to the **Boolean Difference** cutting **Cube**, as in the attached blend file, the cutting shape stops being invisible.

I would like to have a way to materialize the precise area which is being cut through and keep the Cube invisible: either by representing a "fill" material as in the previous question, or by making the inside edge of the Sphere a different material.

***Desired result 1***

[image]

***Desired result 2***

[image]

***Can the "cut" area be materialized with a different material, either the "fill" of the shape receiving the cut or the line along which it is cut?***

[image]

Comment: If the boolean object doesn't have any materials, the first is used. [Here is a modifier stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P76Ie.gif) which produces your desired effect.

Comment: @Leander Thanks! I'm in Cycles! Sorry for not mentioning, I'l add the Cycles tag too. Your setup works with Cycles but not the "Inside" color (a fun add!)

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, the screenshot only features the materials tab to show the stack of the 3 materials, the settings could also be cycles materials.

Comment: @Leander Make the GIF an answer! 